# Manual text in same column as array formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, vlookup, array-formulas

Ive got an array formula with vlookup in. The problem is I also want to allow manual text lines in the same column. When I enter manual text I get the error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in ##

The formula Ive got is as follows:

=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F$4:$F,'MANAGERS TAB'!$A$4:$B$399,{2},1)))

If anyone can help I really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use a formula and manual data entering on the same cell.